# JMeter - Webdriver - Multiple iframe

Tags: jmeter

How to test iframes with jmeter

I have windows with multiple iframes
I tried to used with pkg.SwitchTo().Frame(0)
or  pkg.SwitchTo().Frame("iframe name")

but I received an error : "SwitchTo is not a function in

There is different way to Identify iframes with jmeter?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is `pkg` but the shorthand for the [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) class instance when it comes to the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) is `WDS.browser`

Therefore you can switch to the desired frame as simple as:

```
WDS.browser.switchTo().frame("myFrame")
```

and when you need to switch back:

```
WDS.browser.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)